# ionic 4 how to get the page name?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

```
this.platform.backButton.subscribe(() => {
  // get current active page
  const view = ***NEED HELP HERE**;
  if (view.component.name === 'HomePage') {
    // Double check to exit app
    if (new Date().getTime() - lastTimeBackPress < timePeriodToExit) {
      navigator['app'].exitApp(); // Exit from app
    } else {
      this.presentToast('Press back again to exit App');
      lastTimeBackPress = new Date().getTime();
    }
  } else {
    // go to previous page
    this.nav.goBack();
  }
});
```

I'm trying to use backbutton event in ionic 4. but i'm not able to get current page or view name in app.component.ts

Comment: private router: Router Add in constructor and call `this.router.url` you get page url

Answer (score 1):

goBack() failed me. Ionic4 uses navigateBack(url). I've been searching for a goBack substitute. Unfortunately, goBack is still in the code base, but not documented for Ionic 4... and it doesn't work on all platforms and I expect it to go away based on documentation I've read. I tried to use it, and went back to navigateBack(url).

I've been looking for a non HTML method to go back and only provide a defaultHref in case there is no navigational stack since there is no goBack() much like the ionic back button with a defaultHref, but I haven't found it.

So, for my back button, I've done this (I have two tabs, Home and Map):

```
private tab: string;

constructor(
  private navCtrl: NavController,
  private router: Router
) {
  const url = this.router.url;
  const urlParts = url.split('/');

  this.tab = 'home';
  if (urlParts.includes('map')) {
    this.tab = 'map';
  }
```

And later:

```
  this.navCtrl.navigateBack(`/tabs/${this.tab}`);
```

This methodology should help you navigateBack based on URL. It's the best answer I can give based on the limited information.